# Big Oh nested while

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o

I am having some challenges with big-oh problems. These are NOT homework problems. I am writing these problems to better understand the concept here.

```
function func(n)
{
     int k,i = 0;
     while(k < n){ < --- Guessing this outer loop is O(n/2)
        k = n + 2
        i = 0;
        while(i < k){ <--- Not sure what this is?
            i ++;
            i = i * i;
         }
      }         
}
```

I would really like it if you can explain to me what is going on in the inner loop and how your logic ends up at the big-o notation that you finally end up at.

Comment: Should `k = n + 2` not be: `k = k + 2` or something like that? Now your outer loop is not iterating more than once.

Comment: I guess the time complexity still stays O(n*m).  The inner loop is O(m) and the outer loop, like you mentioned, is O(n/2). Summing up it is O(n*m)/2. 2 is a constant and will become irrelevant to the ratio as the input increases.  I am learning myself. So, I could be wrong.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4800/the-order-of-growth-analysis-of-simple-for-loop) on [cs.se] and the questions linked in Raphael's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @alestanis has provided what looks to me like a much *more* accurate analysis of this problem than those in the comments, I still don't think it's quite right.

Let's create a small test program that prints out the values of `i` produced by the inner loop:

```
#include <iostream>

void inner(double k) {
    double i;

    i = 0.0;
    while(i < k) {
        i ++;
        i = i * i;
        std::cout << i << "\n";
     }
}

int main() {
    inner(1e200);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the result I get is:

```
1
4
25
676
458329
2.10066e+011
4.41279e+022
1.94727e+045
3.79186e+090
1.43782e+181
1.#INF
```

If the number of iterations were logarithmic, then the number of iterations to reach a particular number should be proportional to the number of digits in the limit. For example, if it were logarithmic, it should take around 180 iterations to reach  1e181, give or take some (fairly small) constant factor. That's clearly not the case here at all -- as is easily visible by looking at the exponents of the results in scientific notation, this is approximately doubling the number of digits every iteration, where logarithmic would mean it was roughly adding one digit every iteration.

I'm not absolutely certain, but I believe that puts the inner loop at something like O(log log N) instead of just O(log N). I think it's pretty easy to agree that the outer loop is probably intended to be O(N) (though it's currently written to execute only once), putting the overall complexity at `O(N log log N)`.

I feel obliged to add that from a pragmatic viewpoint, `O(log log N)` can often be treated as essentially constant -- as shown above, the highest limit you can specify with a typical double precision floating point number is reached in only 11 iterations. As such, for most practical purposes, the overall complexity can be treated as `O(N)`.

[Oops -- didn't notice he'd answered as I was writing this, but it looks like @jwpat7 has reached about the same conclusion I did. Kudos to him/her.]

Comment: I agree the inner loop complexity is O(log log N).  I don't know if it is θ(log log N) since (...(((1+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2+ ... )^2 grows notably faster than exp(exp(p/2)) for p passes

Comment: @jwpat7: Yeah, I thought about trying to analyze it a bit more thoroughly, but the result is a number of iterations so close to constant that I have a hard time really caring...

Answer (score 4):

The outer loop, with its test `(k < n)` and its step, `k = n + 2`, will run one time, providing an O(1) factor of complexity.

The inner loop has test `(i < k)` which is to say `(i < n+2)`, and has steps `i++; i=i*i;`  At the end,

```
i = (...(((1+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2+ ... )^2 > n+2`
```

which makes the value of `i` super-exponential.  That is, `i` grows faster than exp(exp(p)) in p passes so that overall complexity is less than O(log log n).  This is a tighter bound than the previously-mentioned O(log n), which also is an upper bound but not as tight.

Answer (score 2):

The second loop squares the value of `i` until it reaches `k`. If we ignore the constant term, this loop runs in `O(log k)` time.

**Why?** Because if you solve `i^m = k` you get `m = constant * log(k)`.

The outer loop, as you said, runs in `O(n)` time.

As bigger values of `k` depend on `n`, you can say the inner loop runs in `O(log n)` which gives you an overall complexity of `O(n log n)`.